# Convert particular sheet in excel to csv

Tags: c#, excel, interop, export-to-csv

How do I convert a particular sheet to CSV from Excel using C# Interop?  Does it default to the first sheet or can I specify?

This is the code i am using:

```
 private void ConvertProgsToCSV()
    {
        Excel.Application app = new Excel.Application();
        Excel.Workbook wb = app.Workbooks.Open(txtFname.Text);
        wb.SaveAs(@"C:\Temp\output.csv", Excel.XlFileFormat.xlCSVWindows);
        wb.Close(false);
        app.Quit();
        Console.WriteLine("Done!");
    }
```

Comment: You can select the tab, then save/convert to CSV. It does not have to be the first tab, but it does have to be explicitly selected. What have you tried/ code do you have so far?

Comment: How do you select the tab?  I don't see any method for this in _Workbook.SaveAs class.

Comment: You need the `Select` method that's part of the [Worksheet object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194464.aspx) (`wb.Worksheet` in your code). Then save as normal!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to open worksheet by it's name and Select it using `Select()` function:

```
xlSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlBook.Worksheets["Sheet1"];
xlSheet.Select(Type.Missing);
xlBook.SaveAs("C:\Filename.csv", Excel.XlFileFormat.xlCSV,Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange);
```

*Assuming that `xlSheet` is of type`Interop.Excel.WorkSheet` and `xlBook` is of type `Interop.Excel.Workbook`*

You can refer to this links for more info:

- [How to: Programmatically Select Worksheets](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x62t5306.aspx)
- [Working with Worksheets](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb157882.aspx)
- [C# with Excel -- How to select a sheet?](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/02419ea7-1666-461e-b9f2-445d82e66322/c-with-excel-how-to-select-a-sheet?forum=vsto)

Comment: I have this error on the first line:  "Non-invocable member 'Microsoft.Office.Interop,Excel._Workbook.Worksheets' cannot be used like a method.

Comment: I have this.  using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

Comment: you have to use `[]` instead of `()` , i fixed the answer